# Print a DIV in landscape in IE/FireFox/Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, printing

I have a `<div>` in my page and want to print it by landscape style in IE/Firefox/Chrome.
I'm using this code to print the div:

```
function print() {
    var frame = $doc.getElementsByClassName('mydivclass').item(0);
    var data = frame.innerHTML;
    var win = window.open('', '', 'height=500,width=900');
    win.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
    win.document.write('</head><body >');
    win.document.write(data);
    win.document.write('</body></html>');
    win.print();
    win.close();
    return true;
}
```

I found this:

```
@page {
  size: landscape;
}
```

but it only works for whole the page. is there any way to print a div in landscape?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
function print() {
    var frame = document.getElementsByClassName('mydivclass').item(0);
    var data = frame.innerHTML;
    var win = window.open('', '', 'height=500,width=900');
    win.document.write('<style>@page{size:landscape;}</style><html><head><title></title>');
    win.document.write('</head><body >');
    win.document.write(data);
    win.document.write('</body></html>');
    win.print();
    win.close();
    return true;
}
```